# ImportError: cannot import name 'executor' from 'aiogram'

Tags: python, aiogram-2.x

```
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
```

установлен aiogram 2 версии

Comment: Проверьте, чтобы у вас файл не назывался aiogram.py, и не было рядом файлов с таким названием.

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install --force-reinstall -v "aiogram==2.23.1"
```

Comment: либо же используй импорт from aiogram.utils import executor

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

```
from aiogram.utils import executor
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).